# How do we know if a typeclass is a sub-typeclass of another typeclass?

Tags: haskell

If we do
`let add a b = a+b`
then `add :: Num a => a -> a -> a`.

We also know that `1.5 :: Fractional a => a`.
And `add 1 1.5` works flawlessly.

If I understand correctly every type which has an instance of `Fractional` has also an instance of `Num`, but how is this fact made explicit?

Comment: can you explain "how is this fact made explicit?" better ? what do you mean exactly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in the definition of the `Fractional` class:

```
class Num a => Fractional a where
   ...
```

You can see it typing `:i Fractional` in GHCi, or on the [Haddock docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional).

Comment: Important to note: Haskell doesn't have "sub-typeclasses," it simply checks that all instances of `Fractional` obey the class context, which in this case expresses a sub-typeclass-like relationship. It is not a special syntax, just a useful idiom.